# Angular - add component from directive

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I have lots of snippets like this one:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="name" />
  <mat-error>{{ form.controls['name'].errors | errorMessage }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Being the `mat-error` line so verbose, is it possible to add it automatically (either with a directive for the `input` or the `mat-form-field`)? If so, what would the approach be? I've been playing around with `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentFactoryResolver` with no useful results for this case...

Comment: What is the goal? To just have less template code, or to have something that is reusable?

Comment: Why don't you put all of this into a reusable component ? Check https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel

Comment: @G.Tranter The goal is to reduce boilerplate code. Gilsdav, I actually thought about that option, but my team is more prone to use Angular (Material) syntax instead of start creating our encapsulated components everywhere. Not sure, though, if what I'm trying is possible at all in Angular >=2.

Comment: Boilerplate code an excellent reason for a reusable component. Your `errorMessage` filter is a reusable 'component' (not `@Component`) already. You could easily create an error message text component that takes the form control as an input and displays the appropriate message via the filter, however it wouldn't really do anything more than what `form.controls['name'].errors | errorMessage` already does. But the gain would be that should you need to change something about it, you only need to change the component, not every instance of that usage pattern.